# Activating a pyenv virtual environment with direnv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv, direnv

I use both `direnv` and `pyenv` and would like to add something to my `.envrc` so that whenever I change directory, I also activate my virtual environment with pyenv.

I printed environment variables both when my virtualenv is active and also when it is not. There were a few pyenv variables set, which I added to my `.envrc` (see below). I was hoping these would activate my pyenv virtual environment upon changing to the directory, but it didn't work.

I'll keep poking at this and trying to sort it out. If I find the answer, I'll update the question with the answer. In the meantime, I'm curious if anyone else has configured `direnv` so that a virtual environment is loaded upon `cd`'ing to a directory. If so, would you mind sharing how you did it?

** DID NOT WORK WHEN ADDED TO .envrc**

```
PYENV_VERSION=ds
PYENV_ACTIVATE_SHELL=1
PYENV_VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/evan/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/envs/ds
VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/evan/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/envs/ds
```

Comment: Do you use pyenv-virtualenv? If so you can put the virtualenv name in a file named `.python-version` and it should automatically activate, see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv.

Comment: @JoshBrobst, you're absolutely right. This works exactly as intended. Thank you. Would you be interested in changing your comment to an answer so I can reward you the bounty on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv) rather than direnv. First, make
sure that `eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"` is run in `~/.bashrc`. Then, to use
a named virtualenv in a particular directory, put the virtualenv name in a file
named `.python-version` in that directory. For example in the directory `~/py`:

```
$ pyenv virtualenv my-venv
$ mkdir ~/py
$ echo my-venv >~/py/.python-version
$ cd ~/py
(my-venv) $ python -V
Python X.Y.Z
```